# From each of two numbers, half the smaller is subtracted, making the larger 4 times as large as the smaller. What is the ratio of the numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, ratio

> From each of two given numbers, half the smaller number is subtracted. After such subtraction, the larger number is $4$ times as large as the smaller number. What is the ratio of the numbers?

A guidance about this problem is most welcome.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  The usual place to start would be to assign variables to the relevant unknowns and then to express the given information in terms of those variables.

Comment: [This](https://www.competoid.com/quiz_answers/14-0-12455/Question_answers/) might answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set L the larger number, s the smaller number, then  you have $L-s/2$ and $s-s/2$ and you know the factor between the two

Comment: Is it 2:5 or 5:2 ?

Comment: both is right $L:s=5:2; and s:L=2:5$